# RubyGems issue on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion

I created a new RoR application, but whenever I run `bundle install` (which installs RSpec along other gems) I get the following error:

> Gem::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in /Users/petarpetrovic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0.gem
>   An error occured while installing selenium-webdriver (2.22.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.22.0'` succeeds before bundling.

When I run `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.22.0'`, I get the following error message:

> ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver:
>     invalid gem format for /Users/petarpetrovic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0.gem

I tried manually removing the gem from cache folder and then rerun `bundle install` but I still get the same error messages.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update gems

```
gem update --system
gem update
```

Check Gemfile in your rails application. Should content: `gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.22.0"`

Run `bundle install` again.

Comment: I think that needs to be `gem update --system`, with a `sudo` in front of it if OP isn't using RVM or similar.

Comment: It seems he is using rvm: /Users/petarpetrovic/.rvm/gems... But gems system update seems to be reasonable too. Thanks :)

Comment: There's no reason to run `gem update` after, especially when using Bundler. Also @MarkReed, while the command *may* need `sudo`, it's better, IMO, to give it without and allow the user to add it if they need to. Running without `sudo` gives at worst a permissions error, running with when you shouldn't works at first but screws up everything.

Comment: To be fair, `gem update` may update `bundler` so it's not entirely useless. A better approach is `gem install bundler`.

Comment: He gets **invalid gem format** error even without bundle by **gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.22.0'**. And selenium-webdriver gem was updated yesturday. I think system update will fix issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the above solution although it might work for someone. I ran into the same error but with different gem. I got problem with nokogiri and got this error message:

```
Gem::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/nokogiri-1.5.5.gem
```

I went to `/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/` and removed the file `nokogiri-1.5.5.gem` and I was able to run bundle again. I think there is something messed up with the .gem file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cached copy of the gem and then try installing it again

```
rm -rf /Users/petarpetrovic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/cache/selenium-webdriver-2.22.0.gem
gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.22.0'
```