# An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.13), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After run bundle install I get this error:

```
Gem::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/cache/libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-12.gem
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I try with

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13'
```

But I get

```
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    invalid gem format for /Users/jeanosorio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/cache/libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-12.gem
```

What is the problem here. Please some help.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I've had the exact same one. I seem to remember being able to get around it with homebrew. I had all kinds of problems with libv8 after upgrading to the Xcode that came out with mountain lion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Gem::Package::FormatError: no metadata found in ...` error message indicates that the content of Ruby's cache directory gets out of sync with the actual gem repository.

The error can be fixed by removing either the offending file or the complete cache folder, and running `bundle install` again.

First try removing the offending file:

```
rm ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/cache/libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-12.gem
bundle install
```

That should fix the problem. If it doesn't, remove the complete cache folder:

```
 rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/cache/
 bundle install
```

Ref:

1. [Rails: Fixing Bundle “No Metadata Found” issues](http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2010/11/rails-fixing-bundle-no-metadata-found-issues/)
2. [Bundler issue : No metadata found](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/603)
3. [SO answer to `RubyGems issue on OSX`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150942/429758)

Additionally, it might be worth updating rubygems version with `gem update --system` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10817676/429758)

Comment: I uninstall and reinstall it with [the argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/rails-gem-install-error-error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-nati) as root. Not works. My Error is `An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.` and  `Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux.gem. It may be corrupted.`  I remove the whole cache and re-run `bundle install --full-index --deployment --without development test postgres aws`. Works.