# failed to install Bundler gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubinius

I've set up [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius) on my mac to give it a shot and see how it behaves with [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma), but I'm having some trouble with installing gems, more specifically the [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) gem. I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing bundler: invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) in /Users/rolandjitsu/.gem/rbx/2.1.0/cache/bundler-1.5.3.gem
```

Does anyone know what is happening? Because I tried finding the reason why it behaves this way, but I could not figure it out why.

**EDIT**: If I remove the cache folder and try a `gem install bundler` I get the following:

```
Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing bundler: invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) in /Users/rolandjitsu/.gem/rbx/2.1.0/cache/bundler-1.5.3.gem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because Ruby's cache directory gets out of sync with the actual gem repository.

Remove cache folder. You can visit this following stack answer here @ [An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.13), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776685/an-error-occurred-while-installing-libv8-3-11-8-13-and-bundler-cannot-continu)

Comment: I have tried that previously, but now it `Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem (100%)` and then I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command to fix that problem:

`bundle update && bundle install`

cheers